# Remove all animation for button ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am creating an application with some up down animation. 
When I click a button the title text move up and label comes from the bottom needs to down after 3 seconds. Look at the following sample image

[image]

This is the origional design. Once I click a button animation working fine. But if I click same item animations messed up. I try to use the following code.

```
self.sub_item.layer.removeAllAnimations() 
item.layer.removeAllAnimations()
self.item.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
self.sub_item.hidden = false

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
  self.bottomConstraint.constant = self.item.frame.height/3.0
  self.item.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-self.item.frame.height/3.0, 0, 0, 0)
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: { finish in
   UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 4.0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
     self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
     self.nitem.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   }, completion: {finish in
    self.sub_item.hidden = true
   })
})
```

**NOTE:** If my question is confusing, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset the constraint while removing all animation as you are doing in button tap:-

```
//remove animation and reset constraints

 self.sub_item.layer.removeAllAnimations()
 item.layer.removeAllAnimations()
 self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
 self.nitem.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
 self.view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
 self.sub_item.hidden = false

//start animation


UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState, animations: {
    self.bottomConstraint.constant = self.item.frame.height/3.0
    self.item.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-self.item.frame.height/3.0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { finish in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 4.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState, animations: {
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
            self.nitem.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: {finish in
            self.sub_item.hidden = true
        })
})
```

Comment: I tried this  self.nitem.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) is not working. Also sub_item is not working properly still some strange things happening.

Comment: I have updated the animation option...Check with this

Comment: I am having many issues first one is. self.nitem.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) is not reseting. Every click it moving up and up. What is the issue here?